# Synchronize database diagram to MySQL SCRIPT?

Tags: mysql, database, jdeveloper, synchronize

I want to know if it's possible to create MySQL Schema from database diagram in jDeveloper 11g??

I created ERD (database diagram) in jDeveloper just for getting it's schema in SQL.
but now i need MySQL schema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can generate database creation scripts (DDL) from DB diagrams in JDeveloper see this tutorial:
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18941_01/tutorials/jdtut_11r2_84/jdtut_11r2_84.html

Comment: Thanks Shmeltzer but I've already created schema in Oracle JDBC. 
My problem is that when i choose MySQL connection Type then it does not find class path for the driver. I have also tried to add MySQL connector library in it but still confused how to create MySQL Connection.

Comment: i'm unable to generate schema of mysql from database diagram using jdeveloper